# How to inherit main part of a class , but change some value (css)

Tags: css

```
.headerValueStyle1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #575f7a;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8%;
}
```

I have this class for example .. I want to inherit all properties from this class, but only change width (make it for example 10%). How to make it? I can copy it 2 times and change it .. but I think it isn't a good way.

Comment: simply use the class and another class to override the width

Comment: make new classes inside headerValueStyle1, but only add there width?

Comment: no I mean use that class and another one for the width .. basically like the answer provided actually

Comment: Thanks for your time) Helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can apply multiple classes to html elements, e.g. `<span class="headerValue width8">`, this will then use both .headerValue and .width8

In combination with a css style sheet like

```
.headerValue{
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #575f7a;
  text-align: left;
}
.width8{
  width: 8%;
}
.width10{
  width: 10%;
}
```

you can achieve such "inheritance" (not actually inheritance but rather what I believe you're looking for)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Good solving.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
.headerValueStyle1,
.anotherClass {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #575f7a;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8%;
}
.anotherClass {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Just rewrite below property